# HTML custom element has no width

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, custom-element

I created custom element and set its dimensions and background color. But in page it dont render anything. In DOM it is present, but not visible.

```
export class BaseLayout extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.style.backgroundColor="red";
        this.style.width = "500px";
        this.style.height = "500px";
    }
}
customElements.define("base-layout", BaseLayout);
```

When I add something (via innerText), red background appear, but only as background to that text (and not for 500px width and height).

One way I solved it is to extends HTMLDivElement instead of HTMLElement. But when I do this, I lost my fancy custom html tags (it will be replaced by DIV). Is there way to avoid that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to set its [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property to something like `'block'` or `'inline-block'`.

```js
this.style.display = 'block';
```

So, your example would look like this:

```js
export class BaseLayout extends HTMLElement{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.style.backgroundColor="red";
        this.style.width = "500px";
        this.style.height = "500px";
        this.style.display = "block";
    }
}
customElements.define("base-layout", BaseLayout);
```